# How to announce streams on Reddit

Tags: stream, reddit

Hi i want to launch subreddit for gamer, 
1. I just want to know how we can announce streams on my sub reddit from twitch or from youtube. Same like watch people code sub reddit do 
2. Can we post automatic messages to other reddits related to gaming category ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interesting in writing a bot, you can find documentation for that here: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api

And some subreddits disallow bots, some don't. You'd have to find out the specifics for that on your own.

Comment: have you written any bot like that ?

Comment: I haven't, but I know a lot of people do it.
Here's a youtube tutorial I found very quickly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4j6ViauHJ8